# How to make negative outputs on html, JS, and css calculator display red?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I am trying to use and if/then comparison to make negative numbers turn red in their output box after being processed through calculator functions. For example, in my adding function, I am using innerHTML with a

tag to display the answer in its own box. But with innerHTML and using a string, I can't figure out how to make negative numbers turn red and positive turn green. I have tried to get help and was told that I need to "do the comparison first" because the if/then is "comparing the string to 0". I am not sure what that means and I don't know how to fix it. I have put my script and the connected HTML.

```js
function powNumbers() {
            var result = 1;
            var val1 = Number(document.getElementById("value1").value);
            var val2 = Number(document.getElementById("value2").value);
            for (let counter = 0; counter < val2; counter = counter + 1) {
            result = answer * val1;
            }
            var ansD = powN;
            var output = document.getElementById("result");
            if (ansD >= 0) {
             output.style.color = "green";
             } else {
             output.style.color = "red";
    }
             output.innerHTML = output;
        }
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <input class="boxes" type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="" /><br />
  <input class="boxes" type="text" id="value2" name="value2" value="" /><br />
  <button class="stripeButtons buttonRound" onclick="addNumbers()">+</button>
  <button class="stripeButtons buttonRound" onclick="subNumbers()">-</button>
  <button class="stripeButtons buttonRound" onclick="multNumbers()">*</button>
  <button class="stripeButtons buttonRound" onclick="divNumbers()">/</button>
  <button class="stripeButtons buttonRound" onclick="powNumbers()">^</button>
  <button class="stripeButtons buttonRound" onclick="clearFields()">Clear</button><br />
  <input class="boxes" type="text" id="answer" name="answer" value="" />
  <p class="boxes" id="result" value=""></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You weren't too far off. In the following code, I made a couple corrections to get you there:

1) You don't need `ansD.value`, it's just `ansD`

2) You need to set the `style` of the output element, not the answer value

```js
function addNumbers () {
    var val1 = Number(document.getElementById("value1").value);
    var val2 = Number(document.getElementById("value2").value);
    var addN = val1 + val2;     
    var ansD = addN;

    var output = document.getElementById("result");

    if (ansD >= 0) {
        output.style.color = "green";
    } else {
        output.style.color = "red";
    }

    output.innerHTML = ansD;
}
```

```html
<div align="center"> 
    <input class="boxes" type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value=""/><br>
    <input class="boxes" type="text" id="value2" name="value2" value=""/><br>
    <button class="stripeButtons buttonRound" onclick="addNumbers()">+</button>
    <button class="stripeButtons buttonRound" onclick="subNumbers()">-</button>
    <button class="stripeButtons buttonRound" onclick="multNumbers()">*</button>
    <button class="stripeButtons buttonRound" onclick="divNumbers()">/</button>
    <button class="stripeButtons buttonRound" onclick="powNumbers()">^</button>
    <button class="stripeButtons buttonRound" onclick="clearFields()">Clear</button><br>
    <input class="boxes" type="text" id="answer" name="answer" value=""/>
    <p class="boxes" id="result" value=""></p>
</div>
```